# Prove that this factor ring is a finite ring without zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, finite-rings

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]=\{a+b\sqrt{d}\mid a,b,d\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and let $d$ be square-free. Let $P$ be a non-zero prime ideal in $R$. I need to prove that the factor ring $R/P$ has no zero divisors and is finite.

How do I do this?

Thank you.